# CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider thread-safe or not?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Some of our users are running into an issue where CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider returns a NULL CGImageRef on OS X (mostly 10.9).

I cannot reproduce the issue, but since we are invoking CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider from a background thread and users keep telling us, that the bug is sporadic, I'm wondering whether CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider is thread-safe at all.

Found this post, where the author claims there's Apple documentation stating its not thread-safe:
[Reading CGImageRef in a background thread crashes the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672506/reading-cgimageref-in-a-background-thread-crashes-the-app/16677411#16677411)

I couldn't find that documentation. Anybody can shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The function itself is thread safe. The problem may be (like in the link you showed) where the data provider comes from. That has to be thread safe as well. In the linked question, it wasn't. So I'd check where the data comes from, and what you are doing once the image is completed.

Comment: I'm calling CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename on the same thread prior to CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider. We have NSLogs in place that suggest CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename returns at least non-nil data.